# D3 mapping with geoJson US Map working but not World

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, geojson

Hi I have been following an example on how to create a geo map using D3 and a Geo Json file.

So far I have created the following no problem using this book:
h**p://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1230000000345/ch12.html#_projections

```
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">

                    //Width and height
                    var w = 500;
                    var h = 300;

                    //Define map projection
                    var projection = d3.geo.albersUsa()
                                       .translate([w/2, h/2])
                                       .scale([500]);

                    //Define path generator
                    var path = d3.geo.path()
                                 .projection(projection);

                    //Create SVG element
                    var svg = d3.select("body")
                                            .append("svg")
                                            .attr("width", w)
                                            .attr("height", h);

                    //Load in GeoJSON data
                    d3.json("us-states.json", function(json) {

                            //Bind data and create one path per GeoJSON feature
                            svg.selectAll("path")
                               .data(json.features)
                               .enter()
                               .append("path")
                               .attr("d", path);

                    });

            </script>
    </body>
```

using this json file: 
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/49159198/us-states.json

When I try to create world map using the following json file (In the same format as US just countries not states) it does not come out right.

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/49159198/countries.geo.json

The US map comes out as a black regtangle. After applying some stroke to the path in CSS I can see that the map is there but this will not work as I need to edit the path later on through data from a CSV.

Code for world map:

```
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">

                    //Width and height
                    var w = 960;
                    var h = 480;



                    var projection = d3.geo.equirectangular()
                                      .translate([w/2, h/2])
                                     .scale([150]);

                                    var path = d3.geo.path()
                                        .projection(projection);

                    //Create SVG element
                    var svg = d3.select("body")
                                            .append("svg")
                                            .attr("width", w)
                                            .attr("height", h);

                    //Load in GeoJSON data
                    d3.json("countries.geo.json", function(json) {

                            //Bind data and create one path per GeoJSON feature
                            svg.selectAll("path")
                               .data(json.features)
                               .enter()
                               .append("path")
                               .attr("d", path);

                    });

            </script>
    </body>
```

Any help would be great as it will be aiding my college project.

***Updated due to answers below***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not use the `albersUsa` projection for anything but the US -- it clips everything outside that area. Instead, use e.g. `albers`.

Comment: Thank you have I have just googled AlbersUsa and realised it used to crop the US States.

I have tried 'ablers' but now my map is just a fully black map>

https://db.tt/5o6cH1iw

Comment: Just need to set CSS so the `path`s are not filled but only stroked -- http://vida.io/documents/GGeSHJQMpoTExsvPT

Comment: CSS method works but this will over rule my future code as I plan on using each path (country) to be filled in a colour depending on a CSV files value. 

The stoke though has shown me that my map is their correctly. My code has no been altered to use `equirectangular` instead of alber. 

It's just the problem that the entire map is black and has no boundaries unlike the US map.

Comment: No, anything you do in code will override the CSS directives. I've changed the example to use the equirectangular projection and it works fine.

Comment: I have tested this css method with adding fill through data and some countries are missing and not filled so this method will not work.

I really can't understand why the US map comes out fine and the World map comes out as a purely blank.

Comment: It would help if you could show some code that demonstrates the problem. I've updated the example again to fill the countries.

Comment: I have edited your code to scale 150. If you have a look you can see Argentina is missing.

http://vida.io/documents/eTReDfWQAZwT8TKao

Comment: What i'm trying to is the following:

create a heat colour map of countries. Data is pulled from a CSV file, the higher the number the stronger the country colour.

example CSV data:
`
state,value
Brazil,1.3791
Spain,1.3705
Japan,1.6847
Russia,1.4334
Argentina,1.4302
Mali,2.3020`

example code of colors on map:
http://vida.io/documents/Wnczr8wdraEYzq287


As you can see some countries are missing.

again thank you for your help.

Comment: Ok, this is a problem with the GeoJSON -- see [here](https://github.com/johan/world.geo.json/issues/10). I've fixed the problem in the example by deleting Bermuda.

Comment: OK so if i delete bermuda from the json file I wont need to use the css to see the map?

Comment: Just deleted bermuda and all is well without CSS. Thank you so much.

Comment: I was debugging this for hours. I tried my own country and it doesn't even assign any path attribute.